# angularjs how to avoid access to a just visited route

Tags: angularjs

Put the case I've got a route like

```
.config(function (CONFIG,$routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: CONFIG.site.path_views + '/index/index.html',
                controller: 'IndexCtrl'
            })
            .when('/contestant/create', {
                templateUrl: CONFIG.site.path_views + '/contestant/create.html',
                controller: 'ContestantCreateCtrl'
            })
            .when('/contestant/thanks', {
                templateUrl: CONFIG.site.path_views + '/contestant/thanks.html',
                controller: 'ContestantThanksCtrl'
            })
            .when('/product', {
                templateUrl: CONFIG.site.path_views + '/product/index.html',
                controller: 'ProductCtrl'
            })
            .when('/prize', {
                templateUrl: CONFIG.site.path_views + '/prize/index.html',
                controller: 'PrizeCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });

    })
```

I'd like to deny access or simply redirect the user
 to /contestant/create if he/she has filled in the form
but I don't find a way :(

Comment: The simplest way is to create a service which hold a reference to every visited route, so you could put a resolve in every route, check if that route is in the services' list and if so, deny it, else, you put it on the list and continue. A expert user could hack that easily. So you could put that list on the server or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.run( function(VisitedRoutes) {
    VisitedRoutes.init();
};
app.factory('VisitedRoutes', function($rootScope,$location) {
        var routes = [];
        return {
            add : function(){
                 routes.push($location.path());
            },
            all:function(){
                return _.uniq(routes);
            },
            hasRoute:function(value){
               return _.indexOf(this.all(), value) 
            },
            init:function(){
                var that = this;
                $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (scope, next, current) {
                    that.add();
                });
            }
        }
    });
app.controller('ContestantCreateCtrl',function($scope,$location,VisitedRoutes) {
    if(VisitedRoutes.hasRoute('/contestant/thanks') !== -1){
        $location.path('/');
    }
});
```

**credit to @Jesus Rodriguez :)**